# Javascript multidimensional object overwriting last inserted item

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to get a MD object in javascript, I have something this at the moment, but it isn't exactly what I want:

```
{"usernames":["Ted","Mikey"],"room_status":[0,0]}
```

The idea is that I want the room status values of 0 assigned to Ted and Mikey at the moment they are not. So I can then use:

```
$.each(usernames, function(index, value){
    //do stuff
})
```

... to loop through the names and see which room status value is assigned to who.. I also tried something along the lines of this:

```
usernames = {
    'username' : {
        'username' : username,
        'room_status' : 0
    }
}
```

which returns:

```
{"username":{"username":"asdfgasdc","room_status":0}}
```

but overwrites the last item...

Comment: Thats because you can only have _one_ key `username`. Try `var people = {"Ted":{"username":"asdfgasdc","room_status":0},"Mike":{"username":"asdfgasdc","room_status":0}}` and then running a basic for loop (not recommended): `for(person in people){ console.log(people[person].room_status)}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var users = [{
    username: 'Ted',
    room_status: 0
}, {
    username: 'Mikey',
    room_status: 0
}];
```

This gives you an array of objects, which you can either loop or access directly

```
$.each(users, function(index, user){
    console.log(user.username + ' - ' + user.room_status);
});
// Ted - 0
// Mikey - 0

var user = users[0];
console.log(user.username + ' - ' + user.room_status);
// Ted - 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could easily use the usernames as keys:

```
var people = {
    Mike: { room_status: 0 },
    Ted: { room_status: 0 }
}
```

And loop through them with a for loop:

```
for(var person in people){
    people[person].room_status
}
```

And even access them directly:

```
people.Mike.room_status
```

It would be more recommended to syphon everyone into a `prototype` and assign that to the `username`, as that way you can easily check for normals in your for loop (aka `if( people[person] instanceof Person ) // run code`, ignoring any possible default functions or prototype functions that may exist for an `object`.

Comment: array makes more sense

Comment: @MaxBurnaye yes, when we are talking about many people with potentially repeated names. For quick accessing, this is more useful.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
usernames = {
    'username' : {
        'username' : username,
        'room_status' : 0
    }
}
```

to

```
usernames[username] = {
    'username' : username,
    'room_status' : 0
}
```

Because the `'username'` key will be overwritten for every loop

```
var usernames = {};
var usernamesList = ["Ted","Mikey"];
for(var i=0;i < usernamesList.length;i++){
    var username = usernamesList[i];
    usernames[username] = {
        'username' : username,
        'room_status' : 0
    }
}
```

will give you

```
usernames : {
    Ted:{username:'Ted',room_status:0},
    Mikey:{username:'Mikey',room_status:0}
}
```

calling:

`usernames['Ted'].room_status` OR `usernames.Ted.room_status` will return `0`

Comment: This usename key will be overwritten as well. You have to use the `[]` syntax if you want to _not_ overwrite it.

Comment: users = { 'ted' :{ room: 0 }, 'mikey':{room:1}}; but i like the array version in Tom Beynons answer

Comment: You got it right in your edits, but please remove the top bit after `to`, as its still not really correct. I get the idea, but code-wise this will cause issues to anyone reading your answer.

Comment: Yeah I didn't see the top part earlier.